# Need examples from German and French, for chapters 31 and 32 on WALS

Tags: linguistic-typology

WALS chapters 31 (wals.info/chapter/31) and 32 (wals.info/chapter/32). I need examples in French and German languages regarding these chapters. One language would be enough too!hello can you please explain the values (chapters) seperately? for one language would be enough!!! I will try to find the whole book! I have just got the whole book but I would like you ti explain the values in a few sentences regarding just one language!

Comment: Welcome to Linguistics.SE! Please expand your question so it were self-sustaining, and so users who'd like to answer it were not required to search for what exactly you mean.

Comment: @erik2 you can comment I guess, if not, it's unclear what you are trying to ask of me (after the edit). Also if my answer was good enough you can upvote it too.

Answer (score 1):

according to what I understand, WALS ch 31 and 32 talk about Gender based systems, Given below is an excerpt from (Gender By Greville G. Corbett) for French (refer to book for more details).

[image: French example]

And this is an excerpt for German (same book):

[image: German example]